# How to show lines in TikZ expanding waves decoration selectively?

Tags: tikz-decorations

I want to show the lines in `expanding waves` decoration of TikZ selectively. By default the decoration produces equidistant lines (from the MWE below)

[image]

That is I don't want to show all the lines, but only some, showing attenuation of the wave with distance from the origin: the lines becoming sparser as the distance increases from the origin. Something like shown in the figure below:
[image]

Another thing that I would like to know, if we can scale the linewidth of the expanding waves with the distance from the origin. For example thicker lines near the origin, which get thinner as the wave moves away from the origin.

Any other method to do this, using a different library perhaps, would also be okay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,thick]
\draw [decoration={expanding waves,angle=55,segment length=2mm},decorate,draw,color=red](0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using the exponential function. It is not simple, but it can be configured in several ways.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  %% Setting the central point
\coordinate (pc) at (0,0);

  %% Defining the wave opening angle
\def\opAng{120.0}

  %% Defining the direction of the waves
\def\dirAng{90.0}

  %% Setting the starting radius
\def\initRad{1.0}

  %% Defining the final radius
\def\endRad{3.0}

  %%  Setting the number of lines
\def\nroWav{9}

  %% Defining the aspect
\def\raz{0.25}

  %% Defining the smallest line width
\def\minLineWidth{0.4}

  %% Setting the largest line width
\def\maxLineWidth{1.2}

\begin{scope}[rotate around ={\dirAng:(pc)}]
\foreach \x in {1,...,\nroWav}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\endRad-((\endRad-\initRad)* (1-exp(\raz*(1-\nroWav)))^-1 )* (1-exp(\raz*(\x-\nroWav))) }
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cx{\r*cos(0.5*\opAng)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\cy{\r*sin(0.5*\opAng)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lw{\maxLineWidth-(\maxLineWidth-\minLineWidth)*\x*\nroWav^-1}
  \draw[red, line width =\lw] (pc)  +(\cx,\cy) arc (0.5*\opAng:-0.5*\opAng:\r);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the calculations that you did, particularly for `/r`?

Comment: I am not fluent in the English language, but I will try.

Try to analyze by parts.

Eliminating part of the expression, replacing with asterisks:

\pgfmathsetmacro\r{\endRad-(**)}

The part of the expression above shows that we will start with the largest radius, and we will subtract parts until we reach the smallest radius.

Comment: Now analyzing the part represented in the comment above by the asterisks:

(\endRad-\initRad)*(1-exp (\raz*(1-\nroWav)))^-1)*(1-exp(\raz*(\x-\nroWav))

Break the above expression into two parts:

 (\endRad-\initRad)*(1-exp(\raz*(1-\nroWav)))^-1)

The stretch of the expression above represents, within the \foreach loop, a constant that indicates how far we will move towards the center.

Comment: Whereas the other part of the expression:

 (1-exp(\raz*(\x-\nroWav))

is the term that varies as a function of \x, decreasing as \x increases. This portion of the expression cuts the value of the previous term into parts that are distributed in a non-linear fashion, where the constant \raz allows you to vary at what rate the value of the exponential function varies.